# How to use nav arg to move to next fragment?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, mvvm

This is my main activity of my app. I'm using nav controller.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var viewModel: NewsViewModel
    lateinit var navController: NavController
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {


        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val newRepository = NewsRepository(ArticleDatabase(this))
        val viewModelProviderFactory = NewsViewModelProviderFactory(newRepository)
        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this , viewModelProviderFactory).get(NewsViewModel::class.java)
//        bottomNavigationView.setupWithNavController(newsNavHostFragment.findNavController())

        val navHostFragment= supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.newsNavHostFragment) as NavHostFragment
        navController= navHostFragment.navController
        bottomNavigationView.setupWithNavController(navController)
    }
```

This the breaking news fragment. The function is same in other fragments so only posting this one

```
class BreakingNewsFragment : Fragment (R.layout.fragment_breaking_news) {

    lateinit var viewModel: NewsViewModel
    lateinit var newsAdapter: NewsAdapter

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        viewModel = (activity as MainActivity).viewModel
        setUpRecyclerView()

        newsAdapter!!.setOnItemClickListener {
            val bundle = Bundle().apply {
                putSerializable("article" , it)
            }
            findNavController().navigate(
                R.id.action_breakingNewsFragment_to_articleFragment2 , bundle
            )
        }
        viewModel.breakingNews.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { response ->
            when(response) {
                is Resource.Success -> {
                    hideProgressBar()
                    response.data?.let { newsResponse ->
                        newsAdapter.differ.submitList(newsResponse.articles)
                    }
                }
                is Resource.Error -> {
                    hideProgressBar()
                    response.message?.let { message ->
                        Log.e("Breaking Fragment", "An error occured: $message")
                    }
                }
                is Resource.Loading -> {
                    showProgressBar()
                }
            }
        })
    }

    private fun hideProgressBar() {
        paginationProgressBar.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
    }

    private fun showProgressBar() {
        paginationProgressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    }

     fun setUpRecyclerView() {

         newsAdapter = NewsAdapter()
         rvBreakingNews.apply {
             adapter = newsAdapter
             layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
         }
    }
}
```

This is made from Youtuber Philip lackner's tutorial. Here's the the link of original project
https://github.com/philipplackner/MVVMNewsApp . His version of fragment is deprecated so i used new fragment view in xml file. so there is an issue in using nav controller.

EDIT -> Forgot to put errors. Here it is

```
2022-10-17 01:08:09.796 3971-3971/com.arpit.newsapp20 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.arpit.newsapp20, PID: 3971
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.hashCode()' on a null object reference
        at com.arpit.newsapp20.models.Article.hashCode(Unknown Source:15)
        at androidx.navigation.NavBackStackEntry.hashCode(NavBackStackEntry.kt:256)
        at java.util.HashMap.hash(HashMap.java:338)
        at java.util.HashMap.put(HashMap.java:611)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.linkChildToParent(NavController.kt:143)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.addEntryToBackStack(NavController.kt:1918)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.addEntryToBackStack$default(NavController.kt:1813)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController$navigate$4.invoke(NavController.kt:1721)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController$navigate$4.invoke(NavController.kt:1719)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController$NavControllerNavigatorState.push(NavController.kt:287)
        at androidx.navigation.fragment.FragmentNavigator.navigate(FragmentNavigator.kt:198)
        at androidx.navigation.fragment.FragmentNavigator.navigate(FragmentNavigator.kt:164)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigateInternal(NavController.kt:260)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.kt:1719)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.kt:1545)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.kt:1472)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.kt:1454)
        at com.arpit.newsapp20.ui.BreakingNewsFragment$onViewCreated$1.invoke(BreakingNewsFragment.kt:31)
        at com.arpit.newsapp20.ui.BreakingNewsFragment$onViewCreated$1.invoke(BreakingNewsFragment.kt:27)
        at com.arpit.newsapp20.adapters.NewsAdapter.onBindViewHolder$lambda-2$lambda-1(NewsAdapter.kt:56)
        at com.arpit.newsapp20.adapters.NewsAdapter.$r8$lambda$FmTlKYZBcoLQp02jU2NS9dL1z-k(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.arpit.newsapp20.adapters.NewsAdapter$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.onClick(Unknown Source:4)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7441)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7418)
        at android.view.View.access$3700(View.java:835)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28676)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7839)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
```

Here is the article class

```
@Entity(
    tableName = "articles"
)
data class Article(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var id: Int? = null,
    val author: String,
    val content: String?,
    val description: String,
    val publishedAt: String,
    val source: Source,
    val title: String,
    val url: String,
    val urlToImage: String
) : Serializable
```

Here is the news adapter class

```
class NewsAdapter  : RecyclerView.Adapter<NewsAdapter.ArticleViewHolder>() {

    inner class ArticleViewHolder(itemView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView)

    private val differCallback = object : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Article>() {
        override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: Article, newItem: Article): Boolean {
            return oldItem.url == newItem.url
        }

        override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: Article, newItem: Article): Boolean {
            return oldItem == newItem
        }
    }

    val differ = AsyncListDiffer(this, differCallback)

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ArticleViewHolder {
        return ArticleViewHolder(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(
                R.layout.item_article_preview,
                parent,
                false
            )
        )
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return differ.currentList.size
    }

    private var onItemClickListener: ((Article) -> Unit)? = null

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ArticleViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val article = differ.currentList[position]
        holder.itemView.apply {
            Glide.with(this).load(article.urlToImage).into(ivArticleImage)
            tvSource.text = article.source.name
            tvTitle.text = article.title
            tvDescription.text = article.description
            tvPublishedAt.text = article.publishedAt

            setOnClickListener {
                onItemClickListener?.let { it(article) }
            }
        }
    }

    fun setOnItemClickListener(listener: (Article) -> Unit) {
        onItemClickListener = listener
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You look like to want to pass the clicked news item to the article fragment. But in your click listener you don't receive the clicked item. Instead you pass something else in "it". I think that's why you get a null pointer exception.
You need something like following:

```
            newsAdapter!!.setOnItemClickListener {
            val newsItem = // get clicked news item from adapter
                newsItem?.let {
                    val bundle = Bundle().apply {
                        putSerializable("article" , it)
                    }
                    findNavController().navigate(
                        R.id.action_breakingNewsFragment_to_articleFragment2 , bundle
                    )
                }
        }
```

Comment: thanks for help but is i still don't under what to assign in newsItem. I have attached newsAdapter class . Please help